# Specifying the return type based on optional parameters

Tags: typescript

```
function f<T>(defaultValue?: T) { return defaultValue; }

const definitelyUndefined = f<string>();      // type: string | undefined
const definitelyString = f<string>('foobar'); // type: string | undefined
```

Is it possible to define `f()` such that `definitelyUndefined` is implicitly `undefined` and `definitelyString` is implicitly `string`?

#### Background

My real world use case is a function I'm working with and want to improve. It is `function f<T>(o: { [key: string]: T }, key: string, defaultValue?: T)` and it returns `key[o]` if it exists, otherwise `defaultValue`. When I provide it a `defaultValue`, I'm guaranteed to get `T` back, but Typescript considers it `T | undefined`.

Comment: My first thought was adding `function f<T>(defaultValue: T): T;` as an overload definition, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your first case, I immediately thought of using an overload, for example:

```
function f<T>(): undefined;
function f<T>(value: T): T;
function f<T>(value?: T) { return value; }

const definitelyUndefined = f();      // type: undefined
const definitelyString = f('foobar'); // type: "foobar"
```

However, for the more complex use case, I think perhaps you can solve it with overloads and more complex generics, for example:

```
function f<T, K extends string & keyof T>(o: T, key: K, defaultValue?: T[K]): T[K];
function f<T, V = undefined>(o: T, key: string, defaultValue?: V): V;
function f<T, V = undefined>(o: T, key: string, defaultValue?: V) {
  return o[key] || defaultValue;
}

const obj = { foo: "123" };

const definitelyUndefined = f(obj, "bar");    // type: undefined
const definitelyNumber = f(obj, "bar", 123);  // type: number
const definitelyString = f(obj, "foo");       // type: string
```

I don't know if this will work for every conceivable scenario (because the return type is determined based on the generic type argument, not the actual function argument), but I think it gets pretty close.

Comment: It's weird your "more complex" example does not run on https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/ UPD: it actually does not run in ts 3.3.3333 locally either.

Comment: @zerkms I see the issue. Odd -- I didn't get the error earlier in the playground (maybe the parser was just a little slow). I'll see if I can correct it.

Comment: This line (`function f<T>(): undefined;`) cleared it up for me. Without it TS was complaining that `An argument for 'defaultValue' was not provided.` Once I added that it worked like a charm. Your second example is great for me to learn from, but my actual use case has a few caveats I left out so I wouldn't be able to use it (see `getFieldValue` [here](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss/blob/master/packages/sitecore-jss/src/layoutDataUtils.ts)).

Comment: @zerkms Updated, but I'm still not 100% happy with the provided solution. It still conflates 'type space' and 'value space' but I'm not sure if that can be avoided without more restrictions on `T`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g it looks good to me - I was half-way writing a similar answer right when you posted it :-)

Comment: what is the usage of `V = undefined`?

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer conflates 'type space' and 'value space' (as one of the comments states).
This is suboptimal. Here is an alternative:

**Typescript >= 4.7.4**

```
// Type definition
type ValueElseUndefined<T> =
  T extends (string | number | boolean | symbol | object) ? T : undefined;

// Function definition
function f<T>(defaultValue?: T): ValueElseUndefined<T> {
  return defaultValue as any;
}

// Invocations
const definitelyUndefined = f();      // type: undefined
const definitelyString = f('foobar'); // type: string
```

**Typescript < 4.7.4**

```
// Type definition
type ValueElseUndefined<T> =
  T extends (string | number | boolean | symbol | object) ? T : undefined;

// Function definition
function f<T>(defaultValue?: T): ValueElseUndefined<typeof defaultValue> {
  return defaultValue as any;
}

// Invocations
const definitelyUndefined = f();      // type: undefined
const definitelyString = f('foobar'); // type: string
```

Comment: gives me `const definitelyString: string | undefined` in typescript 4.7.4